# How do I force an ASP web application to refresh itself?

Tags: asp-classic, internet-explorer-8

I've made some changes to a query that an ASP page uses, and now I need to see if those changes did what I expect.  But, the dumb app won't refresh itself, and I don't know how to force it.  I cleared my browser history (IE 8).  What else is there?

I'm pretty sure it is classic ASP, not something from this millenia like ASP.Net

Comment: I wasn't planning on changing the programming of the page, but if this does better belong on StackOverflow, how do I move it there?  Or, do I just delete it and re-ask it there?

Comment: Don't know how you can move it, but I flagged it so a moderator will take a look and move it if needed.

Comment: Could be a rogue proxy server in between. Try appending a random query string to your page urls e.g. http://www.myapp.com/sometestpage.asp?1234 or http://www.myapp.com/someotherpage.asp?CategoryID=1&5678

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clear the cache from an html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657133/how-do-i-clear-the-cache-from-an-html-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be output caching done by your server.  I'm not aware of a specific mechanism for this with classic asp, but I know asp.net has the ability built in and there are things you can do with IIS itself to make this work.

To get around it, change the url in a harmless way, for example by adding a query parameter not used in your page.

Comment: That didn't work, but this particular app is such a Baba Yaga Piece Of Software that I suspect that nothing would work.  If other people voted this up, indicating that it IS a correct answer, then I'll accept it.